# How to iterate through layers of an MXD?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, iterator

I know model builder will not iterate through the layers in an MXD, which is kind of fundamentally stupid if you ask me, but I still need to do exactly that.  I am not a strong coder but i understand Python is how to handle this.

I have seen other questions addressing this, but they seem over-my-head in complexity (i have taken an 'intro to python' university course and did well in it, plus did all the ESRI tutorials, still doesn't help understand how this works).  I am hoping someone here can post some simple cut-n-paste python I can use to accomplish this.

I need to iterate through the ToC and export each layer as a shapefile to a specific folder.  The folder is always the same, but the ToC will change depending on the application, so I have different MXD's for each subset of layers that need to be exported, which is why i want to script/model this as then i can open any MXD and run a tool to get my outputs.

Comment: Please include any arcpy code you've attempted (edit the question and add your code)

Answer (score 9):

To answer your specific question "How to iterate through layers of an MXD?"

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  # Uses your currently open MXD
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0] # Chooses the first dataframe
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
    # Any tools you want to run on each layer go here
```

Something like this should work - just gets a list of all layers in your current map and outputs them to a single folder as shapefiles.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  # Uses your currently open MXD
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0] # Chooses the first dataframe

destPath = r"N:/VisualStudio/Projects/GISSE/Output" # Set your destination folder path

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
    # Output layer to shapefile
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyr, destPath, "{}.shp".format(lyr), "", "", "")
```

Comment: Could be easily modified to allow you to specify the MXD or to change the output folder as tool parameters

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, trying to make it work but get an error that the layer is not a feature layer, so wondering how that is set within the script?

Comment: Try using `if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:` before the `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass`.  See [Layer ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#P_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878)

Comment: Still getting errors, likely syntax?  I have tried a few variants of where to put the IF statement before the output but no luck.  Currently have this: 

destPath = r"V:\iPads\Town GIS data\TEST" # Set your destination folder path

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
     # Output layer to shapefile
     if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:
 arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(lyr, destPath, "{}.shp".format(lyr), "", "", "")

Comment: another detail which could be adding to the confusion; the layers in my MXD are in groups.  I could take them out of the group to have a flat structure to the ToC without too much detriment though if that's what is keeping this from working.

Comment: a-ha!  it was the grouping layers, so i have pulled the layers out of the groups and it works now, THANKS!

Comment: Yes, grouped layers need to be worked around which can add a bit more complexity