# Clip each layer in mxd with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

In the arcpy window in arcgis, I'm trying to:

- iterate through each layer in an mxd
- clip the layer to a shapefile (also in the mxd)
- export each clipped layer to a geodatabase, with the name of each new clipped feature class being the same as the input layer.

My code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]
import os
workSpace = r"J:\foo\bar\test.gdb"
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    fullPath = os.path.join(workSpace, lyr)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr, "clipping_shape", fullPath)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Layer' has no len()
```

Edited to add: above error message appears even without the clip_analysis portion of the code, so presumably something is off with the fullPath variable.

I've read [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/how-to-iterate-through-layers-of-an-mxd) but I don't know how to use this portion of the code when populating a geodatabase instead of using shapefiles.

```
"{}.shp".format(lyr)
```

Comment: `"{}.shp".format(lyr)` just helps name the shapefile.  In this case you shouldn't need it as you're saving to a geodatabase not a shapefile.  Is that the entire error message?

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo whole message is:
 Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\ntpath.py", line 66, in join
    p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\ntpath.py", line 114, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'Layer' has no len()

Comment: @Midavalo I've added more information to the question under the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `os.path.join` is throwing the error.  This can be fixed by changing that line to

```
fullPath = os.path.join(workSpace, lyr.name)
```

although personally I'd remove it and use the following:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]
workSpace = r"J:\foo\bar\test.gdb"
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
    fullPath = r"{}\\{}".format(workSpace, lyr)
    if lyr.name <> "clipping_shape":
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr, "clipping_shape", fullPath)
```

In the line `fullPath = r"{}\\{}".format(workSpace, lyr)` the `{}` are placeholders for text that are input from the `.format(workSpace, lyr)` where `workSpace` goes into the first `{}` and `lyr` into the second to construct the full path.  So if your layer name (`lyr`) was "testlayer" you'd end up with `fullPath = r"J:\foo\bar\test.gdb\testlayer"`

I also added the line `if lyr.name <> "clipping_shape"` otherwise you'll be clipping your clipping_shape as well.  You can remove this line if you still want it to do that.

Comment: why replace os.path.join with a format string? why not just replace **lyr** with **lyr.name** in fullPath?

Comment: for me it's personal preference and not needing to import `os`.

Comment: but yes that would do it too